# Dot underscore (._) files reappear

Tags: filesystem

I have an external USB drive that is formatted with ExFAT. I'm on MacOS Ventura. I noticed that some of my files on that drive have attributes that I deleted with `xattr -cr`. The attributes vanished but now I have thousands of dot underscore files (`._`) on my drive, sometimes tens of `._` before the file name, e.g. `._._._._._._._._myfile.txt`. I tried to delete them with `dot_clean` but they reappear seconds later. How do I prevent the generation of `._`files?

Comment: ExFAT cannot handle unix permissions, extended attributes or ACLs. That's the `._` file's job. You cannot prevent their creation. I'm really not sure what trying to remove xattrs from a file that can't contain them would do… but probably not what you want. Unless you really need this for cross-platform use, avoid ExFAT on Mac. For cross-platform you're better off in the long term using HFS+ & 3rd party software on other platforms that can read HFS